# Go to definition in new tab without changing the view

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I do command + click in Visual Studio Code or right click and "go to definition", the file containing the definition opens in a new tab and I automatically see this file. So I change the view if the file containing the definition is another file.

Is it possible when I do this command to stay on the same file I was while still opening the other file in another tab?

Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 37):

Preferences >> Settings >> Workbench >> Editor >> Enable Preview >> Uncheck/false

Comment: Wow, I'd never guessed this setting does what it does.

Comment: Thanks! After learning what this does, now I just double click on the tab to un-preview it, then it will stay when I "go to definition"!!

Comment: Why is this NOT the default setting?  If a person does not stay on a line of code in a 10,000 line program file, where does their focus go?  The main reason you choose "Go to Definition", "Go to Declaration" or "Go to References" is to do a quick check you're doing something correct in the code you're in.

Comment: Seems to be broken. Still opens a new window if the other one is in a different split (Version: 1.74.3).

Answer (score 8):

If you're capable to actually go to the definition you are looking for what is called the "Peek Definition".  VS Code is highly customizable so how you have it configured it could do something different.

What I think you're looking for is Ctrl + Left Mouse Click or Alt + F12.

This should tell you more, [VS Code Peek Definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek)

Answer (score 5):

On mac, I can `cmd + options + click` the target class/function to open in a new tab on the side. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

You can also *peek definition* with `Alt` + `F12` (be sure to highlight its symbol / invocation first).

This opens the definition in a smaller resizable tab (resizable down to ~4 lines of code) and allows editing if needed.

Example ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-and-edit-code-by-using-peek-definition-alt-plus-f12?view=vs-2019#open-a-peek-definition-window)):
[image: peek window]

Answer (score 3):

Double clicking on the tab name also works if you don't want to disable preview feature of editor. Double clicked tab becomes persistent.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

> If a language supports it, you can go to the definition of a symbol by pressing F12.
> If you press Ctrl and hover over a symbol, a preview of the declaration will appear.
> Tip: You can jump to the definition with Ctrl+Click or open the definition to the side >with Ctrl+Alt+Click.